ASPNET WebApi - POST object with sub list
Using .NET ASPNET WebApi.
I have a simple model. A Song and an Artisk, where a song can have multiple Artists and an Artist can be related to many Songs - a Many-To-Many relation ship.
public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Born { get; set; }
}

 public class Song
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
     public Genre? Genre { get; set; }
     public ICollection<SongArtist> Artists { get; set; }
 }

public class SongArtist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Song Song { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}

I am building an API op the model, and I was wondering how the best way to handle POST. Obviously I need to add multiple Artists when creating a Song. I can see 3 possible solutions:

I am using DTO objects, show I just add a list on the ArtistDTO. Something like this:
public class SongDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ArtistDto> Artists { get; set; }

}

And then provide it in body.

Read a array of IDs from the query

Seperate endpoint to add and delete artists on a song?


Tried to find information on the topic without luck.

What exactly is your question? Are you looking for an example how you can POST your model to a web API?

Establishing Many-to-Many relationship with EF is bit tricky. This requires some change to your existing DTO and it would be like
Entity Classes
public class Song
{
    public int SongId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public Genre? Genre { get; set; }
    public List<Artist> Artists { get; } = [];
}
 
public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Born { get; set; }
    public List<Song> Songs { get; } = [];
}

public class SongArtist
{
    public int SongId { get; set; }
    public Song Song { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}

Then to make the EF to understand the Many-to-Many relation you can use the OnModelCreating overridden method as below
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Song>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Artists)
        .WithMany(e => e.Songs)
        .UsingEntity<SongArtist>();
}

I would suggest to go through the Many-to-many with named join table. This MSDN link will provide various ways you can establish Many-to-Many relation and how to achieve cascade on delete as well.
